# window.print() not working in browser extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, popup, browser-extension

I am trying to make a print browser extension using `window.print()` but it is not working, whereas as a  separate HTML file it is working.

Below are `popup.js` and `print.html`

```js
document.getElementById("m").addEventListener("click", myFunction);

function myFunction() {
  window.print();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <h2>The window.print() Method</h2>
  <button id="m"> click me </button>
</body>
<script src="popup.js">
</script>

</html>
```

manifest file is

```js
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "print",
  "version": "0.10002",
  "content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
    "js": [
      "popup.js",
      "content.bundle.js"
    ],
    "run_at": "document_idle",
    "matches": ["https://*/*"]
  }],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "print.html"
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "background.bundle.js",
      "background.js"
    ]
  },
  "permissions": [
    "storage",
    "https://*/*"
  ]
}
```

Comment: could you provide more details about you trying to implement it as an extension? the problem seem to be there, as the syntax seems right (and you mentioned it does work independently)

Comment: Your code tries to print the extension's popup. You need to run window.print() in your content script e.g. `chrome.tabs.executeScript({code: 'window.print()'})`

Comment: @wOxxOm, can you write the whole Html, js code, because I really think that out of all answers, your answer is only somewhat correct. i mean what to write in html file, js file.

Comment: Simply replace your `window.print()` with my code.