# how to print popup.html window contents with javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, popup, magnific-popup, printers

We have a Chrome extension and we'd like to print the contents of the popup.html.

Does anyone know how I can print this with javascript?

THANK YOU!!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Print the contents of a DIV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255291/print-the-contents-of-a-div)

Comment: See my comments in the [same-topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70545331/window-print-not-working-in-browser-extension).

Answer (score 0):

To print a page in JS you need the `print()` method of the `window` object:

```
function printPage(){
      window.print()
   }
```

but if you want to print a single element [See This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255291/print-the-contents-of-a-div)

Comment: thank you! but it seems unable to call print in popup.html

Comment: Hmm.. It seems to work for me, make sure you don't name your function only 'print' because it will not work.

Comment: i've tyied this         <a href="popup.html" onclick="window.print();return false;" style="font-size: 30px;">
            print</a>  but it just 
refreshed the popup window